# Comparison of two vectors of unequal length

Tags: r

I was trying this out, trying to subset a data frame based on values in vector being in another vector:

```
x <- c( 1,2,3,1,2,3 )
df <- data.frame(x=x,y=x)
df[ df$x == c(1,2), ]
```

expecting to get this:

```
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 2
4 1 1
5 2 2
```

but I didn't, I got this:

```
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

Disregarding the fact that I really wanted this (occurred to me a minute later):

```
df[ df$x %in% c(1,2), ]
```

What is the logic behind the result of this:

```
x == c(1,2)
```

being this:

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I don't really get it. I am aware that this is likely a duplicate, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: You are comparing `x` with `c(1,2, 1, 2, ...)` up till it recycycles the length of `x`

Comment: Hmm. Then the result should be a vector of length 3 I suppose, not length(x).

Comment: Your example doesn't work. `df$x = c(1,2)` is not a correct syntax.

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong line  - fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is based on the recycling of `c(1,2)` to the length of 'x', i.e. we are comparing `df$x` with

```
rep(c(1,2),length.out= nrow(df))
#[1] 1 2 1 2 1 2

df$x ==rep(c(1,2),length.out= nrow(df))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

It means, we are comparing the corresponding elements of 'x' with the corresponding recycled `c(1,2)` instead of checking any element of 'x' contains `c(1,2)`